# Android client-server communication

Tags: android, udp

Unable to receive messages from the server to client and even though i m able to send messages from client to server I had to change the port number most of the times because when i run the server it gives me error saying "address already in use" but once i change the port number it works fine for client-server.

Server Code :

```
 import java.net.*;

    class UDPServer
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
            {
                DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(7683);

                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                    byte[] sendData= new byte[1024];

                    while(true)
                        {
                            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                            System.out.println("RECEIVED:" + sentence);
                            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                            int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                            String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                            sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                            //serverSocket.close();
                        }
            }
    }
```

Client code :

```
BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("000.00.0.000");
                byte[] sendData = new byte [1024];
                byte[] receiveData = new byte [1024];
//                String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
                String sentence = "Hello";
                sendData = sentence.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 7683);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + sentence);
                clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `"address already in use"`. If you close or kill your server you should close the socket first to prevent this message.

Comment: I m not able to receive messages from the server to client and i m able to send messages from client to server but i had change the port number every time i run the server

Comment: Do you mean you want me to close socket at the server ??